# Help calculating a math limit

Tags: limits

Can anyone help with this limit?

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 4}
\frac{16\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}-3\sqrt{2}x-4\sqrt{2}}{16(x-4)^2}
\end{equation*}

I've tried a variable change of  \begin{equation*} y=\sqrt{x} \end{equation*} but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: we have $$\frac{16\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{2}(3x+4)}{16(x-4)^2}$$
multiply numerator and denominator by
$$16\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{2}(3x+4)$$
the numerator is given after this multiplication as
$$-2 \left(\sqrt{x}-2\right)^2 \left(9 x+36 \sqrt{x}+4\right)$$
and write $$x-4$$ as $$(\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+2)$$
after all you will get this term
$$\frac{-2(\sqrt{x}-2)^2(9x+36\sqrt{x}+4)}{(\sqrt{x}-2)^2(\sqrt{x}+2)^2(16\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{2}(3x+4))}$$
after cancelling $$(\sqrt{x}-2)^2$$ you can calculate the limit

Comment: tried it but nothing

Comment: I have added something to my post read this

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Set $x=4+h\;(h\to 0)$ and apply repeatedly *Taylor's formula* at order $2$.

Comment: Taylor repeatedly ?

Comment: Because there's a nested square root.

Answer (score 0):

The variable change is a good idea to begin with, but I'd use $2y=\sqrt{x}$
$$
\lim_{y\to 1}
\frac{16\sqrt{4y^2-2y}-12\sqrt{2}\,y^2-4\sqrt{2}}{16(4y^2-4)^2}=
\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{256}
\lim_{y\to 1}
\frac{4\sqrt{2y^2-y}-(3y^2+1)}{(y^2-1)^2}
$$
You can do this with a Taylor expansion or by “rationalizing”: note that
$$
16(2y^2-1)-(3y^2+1)^2=-9y^4+26y^2-17=-(y^2-1)(9y^2-17)
$$